# Center-allign the title in autoplot

Tags: r, plot, alignment, data-visualization, text-alignment

In the code below, how can I align title `(main ="Maximum Annual Temperature Data In Celsius")` to the center of the plot?

```
autoplot(maxtemp, xlim = c(1990,2020), xlab = "Year", ylab = "Temperature in Celsius", 
                  main ="Maximum Annual Temperature Data In Celsius", colour = "orange")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It should be [minimal, but complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question should be clear and specific. Would you [edit] your question and add output of `dput(head(maxtemp))`?

Comment: Add this: `+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))`

Comment: Excellent. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can center the title if you put a wrapper around the plot and justify it in the theme():

```
#save your plot in a variable
p <- autoplot(maxtemp, xlim = c(1990,2020), xlab = "Year",
     ylab = "Temperature in Celsius",
     main ="Maximum Annual Temperature Data In Celsius",
     colour = "orange")

#now justify title in theme()
p +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Should do it...